# Show that whenever $r \gt 2$ , the series $\sum |n+m\tau|^{-r}$ converges uniformly in every half-plane Im$(\tau)\ge \delta \gt 0$

Tags: complex-analysis, elliptic-functions

> Show that whenever $r \gt 2$ , the series $$\sum_{(n,m)\neq (0,0),n,m\in Z} |n+m\tau|^{-r}$$ converges uniformly in every half-plane Im$(\tau)\ge \delta \gt 0$ .

Note that $$\sum_{(n,m) \neq (0,0), n,m\in Z}(|n|+|m|)^{-r}$$ converges whenever $r \gt 2$ . So it suffice to prove $$|n+m\tau| \ge c(|m|+|n|)$$
For all $\tau\in C$ with Im$(\tau)\ge \delta$ .
If $\tau =s+it$ , then we have $$|n+m\tau|=[(n+ms)^2+(mt)^2]^{\frac12}\ge \frac{|n+ms|+|n\delta|}{2}$$ $$\ge \frac{\min \{\delta , 1 \}}{2}(|n+ms|+|m|)$$
The hint in Stein's complex analysis Page$_{269}$ was to consider two cases when $|n|\le 2|m||s|$ and $|n| \ge 2|m||s|$ to show that $$|n+ms|+|m|\ge c(|n|+|m|)$$
When $|n|\ge 2|m||s|$ , then we have $$|n+ms|+|m|\ge |n|-|ms|+|m|\ge |n|-|n|/2+|m|\ge \frac{|n|+|m|}{2}$$

When $|n|\le 2|m||s|$ , then we have $$|n|+|m|\le 2|m||s|+|m|\le (2|s|+1)(|n+ms|+|m|)$$  However , this estimate depends on $|s|$ .

Comment: Show that $|n+m\tau|^2 \ge c_\tau (m^2+n^2)$ where $c_\tau$ is found from $|\det\pmatrix{1 & 0\\ \Re(\tau)&\Im(\tau)}|$ then say $\sum_{n,m} (m^2+n^2)^{-r/2}\le A+\iint_{x^2+y^2>1} (x^2+y^2)^{-r/2}dxdy=A+\int_1^\infty v^{-r} 2\pi vdv$

Comment: @reuns If we can show $|n+m\tau|^2 \ge c(m^2+n^2)$ , then we have $|n+m\tau| \ge c'(|m|+|n|)$ and the proof is complete . However , how to find such $c$ independent of $\tau$ ?

Comment: Well the series doesn't converge uniformly, it only converges absolutely (because $f(\tau)=\sum_{n,m} |n+m\tau|^{-r}$ is $1$-periodic, it is non zero but the first few terms of $f(\tau+k)$ converge $\to 0$ as $k\to\infty$) and uniformly on $\Im(\tau)\ge\delta>0,|\Re(\tau)|\le L$.

Comment: @reuns But in Stein's complex analysis Page $_{269}$ . It states that when $r \gt 2$ the series $\sum|n+m\tau|^{-r}$ converges uniformly in every half-plane $Im(\tau) \ge \delta \gt 0$. And I did'n see why the 1-periodic property implies $f$ doesn't converges uniformly .

Comment: Because $\lim_{k \to \infty} f(\tau+k)=f(\tau) \ne 0$ while all the terms of its series converge to $0$. If it is really in Stein then it is a mistake. The periodicity implies it suffices to look at $|\Re(\tau)| \le 1/2$ in which case it does converge uniformly.

Comment: Another reference: Exercise 1.1.4 in *A First Course in Modular Forms* by Diamond & Shurman.

Comment: What I'm saying is very elementary...

Comment: @reuns I see , very appreciate for you help!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

$$f(\tau)=\sum_{(n,m)\neq (0,0),n,m\in Z} |n+m\tau|^{-r}$$
doesn't converge uniformly on $\Im(\tau)\ge\delta$, it only converges absolutely.

This is because all the $m\ne 0$ terms of $f(\tau+k)$ converge to $0$ as $k\to \infty$, if the convergence was uniform it would imply $\lim_{k \to \infty} f(\tau+k)=2\zeta(2)$ which isn't the case because $f(\tau+k)=f(\tau)>2\zeta(2)$.

From the $1$-periodicity it suffices to look at $|\Re(\tau)|\le 1/2$ in which case it does converge uniformly:

From $$\pmatrix{n\\ m} =\pmatrix{1 & \Re(\tau)\\ 0&\Im(\tau)}^{-1}\pmatrix{n+m\Re(\tau)\\ m\Im(\tau)}$$ show that $|n+m\tau|^2 \ge c_\delta (m^2+n^2)$ and look at $\sum_{n,m} (m^2+n^2)^{-r/2}\le A+\iint_{x^2+y^2>1} (x^2+y^2)^{-r/2}dxdy=A+\int_1^\infty v^{-r} 2\pi vdv$.